# Как можно отдельно построить фильтры для запроса в Sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

В django есть Q object который позволяет создать определённый фильтр. Есть ли такой же у Sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 0):

В Алхимии грубо говоря есть поддержка Q-объектов из коробки, правда нужно использовать  filter а не filter_by, да и вообще советую всегда использовать filter. Вы можете просто записать clause в переменную и потом использовать в фильтре, например:

```
clause1= case([
    (Application.using_priority_rights==True, 1),                           
],
else_=1000)

clause2= case([
    (func.coalesce(AbiturPerson.achievements, '') != '', 1),                                  
], 
else_=1000)

clause3 = (AbiturPerson.id==Application.id)
clause4 = (AbiturPerson.id==5)

query1 = query.filter(clause3).order_by(
    clause1,                                    
    clause1,
)

query2 = query.filter(
    clause1==1000,                                    
)   

query3 = query.filter(*[clause3, clause4 ])
```

Если нужны различные AND/OR  комбинации условий - то используйте экспрессию 
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=and_#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=and_#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_